# Build 2015, vNext, Trigger scheduled build as nightly only if sources have changed since last build

Tags: build-process, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

how can i have scheduled builds to run only when there were changes in the source code since the last scheduled build?

Like as it was with the old xaml based version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In new build system of TFS 2015, scheduled build doesn't have the option "Build event if nothing has changed since previous build".

As an alternative, you can use CI build instead of scheduled build. Meanwhile, I have submitted a UserVoice at website below, you can vote it, Product Team will evaluate it carefully:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/16300498-add-build-event-if-nothing-has-changed-since-prev

Comment: I wanted to have one build for our QA which consists of everything checked-in the day before. CIs are not suitable in that case, because there can be alot of changes in one day and i don't want to have our QA to search the suitable build for them or rmaybe take one accidently which isn't suitable.
And for space saving thoughts, i just wanted to have a triggered build like before, when the have been changes. No rule without exception, sometimes there arent any changes over days and then you dont need to have one build for every day when there is no difference